# Can Graphhopper store and read data from a third party graph database?

Tags: graphhopper

Can Graphhoper store and read data from a third party graph database like Titan (http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/) or a Tinkerpop Blueprints (http://www.tinkerpop.com/) compatible graph database?

Answer (score 1):

There is old work regarding this issue [here](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper-experiments) for Neo4J and tinkerpop. But this is no longer a priority and community contributions would be highly appreciated. E.g. import/export modules or an alternative GraphHopperStorage implementation would be interesting.